# Mac Book Air runnign Mac OS, Windows8, and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, mac

I hear of people installing Ubuntu side by side with Mac OS but I must have Windows 8 too for my work.  Is it possible to boot all three OS's in a Mac Book Air?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu would work, but for Windows 8, you will need Boot Camp. This link should help you with Boot camp for Win8. (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5628). The hardware itself will handle it. The main concern is Windows, but Boot Camp will fix that. Here is documentation for installing Ubuntu on a Macbook Air (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro).

Comment: Using bootcamp is a messy solution, since it will only show windows as a another boot option. Meaning that you have to add grub to your windows partition.

Comment: True, that can be a hassle.